# PXE at the top of BIOS boot sequence

Tags: boot, bios

I was wondering what happens if we put PXE as the top boot order priority ( before HDD) ? Every time a server reboots, will the server try to PXE boot and not boot from the HDD ( assume that there is an OS loaded in the HDD)

Answer (score 1):

Boot order priority will just try whichever device you put in order until one is found that is bootable. So if PXE has no bootable info then it will try the next one in the list.

Priority is just that. It tries in order until it succeeds regardless of whether ones lower down in the list (I.e. your HDD) are bootable or not.

Comment: So are you saying that if pxe is the first option, it will pxe at every server reboot ?

Comment: I am saying it would attempt to boot via PXE resources before things that are lower priority than it every time it reboots. If PXE services are available on your network to instruct your computer how to boot, then it will choose PXE. If PXE services are not available (i.e. machine is offline or PXE servers aren't up), then it will fail that process and move to the next higher priority order in the boot sequence. You can read about boot sequencing online anywhere. Here's a link to get you started: https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/b/bootsequ.htm

Comment: That does not answer my question though ! I understand you are talking about the order, but my question is very specific - it has a yes / no answer. If we put PXE as the top boot order priority ( before HDD), every time a server reboots, will the server try to PXE boot and not boot from the HDD ( assume that there is an OS loaded in the HDD) ?

Comment: Yes. It will try to PXE boot first.